# Is possible to change references (dlls) default build folder in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to change the references build folder? I want my dlls when i compile to be in a /bin/Debug/Data and not in /bin/Debug.

Thank you

Update 1: Is it possible when i build the references dlls are posted in another folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [load a DLL reference from a different folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009047/load-a-dll-reference-from-a-different-folder)

Comment: Do you want to change the folder where "Copy Local" references are copied to while building?

Comment: Yes i want to change the folder where "copy local" references are copied. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Post-build Event** in project properties.
Using this event you can copy dll file any other place or directory after build 
but dll project must be added in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Projct properties. Tab "Build". Change Output path[image]

Comment: He want to place executable in different folder and DLLs into different, so it is not answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong I believe you can using  Element . You can do this in app.config file The following example shows how to specify application base subdirectories the runtime should search for assemblies.

Personally I have not tested this. I found this in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_assembly.php) article demonstrating **Setting a Custom Reference Path**

Add the following line before the main Form is initialized

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(@"bin\Data");
```

Comment: Ok, but when i build how the dlls go to that folder? I can create a post build action, but i want to publish my application and the dlls are not in the /bin/Data folder.

Comment: Have you copied your required Dlls into data?

Comment: Well let me explain better.
1. I add references by nuget package manager.
2. I use that things to do stuff in my project.
3. Build the project then the dlls are built in the /bin/debug folder.
I want them to go to /bin/debug/Data folder.