# location of external dlls in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I am a newbie to c# and developed a small WPF application which depends on a external dll files. I have added it as reference in the visual studio and started using the methods in side it.

I started to face the problem when I am deploying this utility to other computers. It is mandating me to place the external dll file in the same location of WPF exe file. And I want to avoid this. Instead I want it to look a specific folder(local or remote).

Is it possible to do this way?

Thanks,
Sitaram

Comment: How are you deploying your application? Do you use `ClickOnce`?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445556/c-sharp-putting-the-required-dlls-somewhere-other-than-the-root-of-the-output

Comment: there are lots of ways to deploy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776.aspx

Comment: Almost any program deploys as a single file.  Called setup.exe.  Very easy to do with a Setup project.

Comment: This thread might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I will go through the links you provided and get back to you.

Comment: @Liam : I did that. I am sorry for not paying attention to marking them as answers before. But it is not definitely negligence.I value the peoples efforts and will try to keep up self in marking them as answers where ever applicable. Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to set the LocalCopy Property of the Reference to true. That will copy it to your output exe.

A very bad solution would be to load the assembly manuall in code (Assembly.Load) and add it to your AppContext.

Comment: Any example about how to load a assembly manually in code? Though it is bad, I just want to try if it fits my needs.