# Build DLL to a separate folder

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winforms, nuget-package

**First**

> There are several questions similar to this, but **none** have answers
>   that solved my problem nor can I post in them. The closest one is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2445556/5734097).
>
> I found the answer [here](http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/visual-studio-build-dlls-to-separate.html). And I am posting here so I can found it
>   later.

**The Question:** How to build my project and have all my `Referenced Library` inside a `lib` sub-folder?

A want this output directory:

[image: Lots of DLLs in the main folder]

To be stay like this:

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> I found the answer [here](http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/visual-studio-build-dlls-to-separate.html) and transcribed here for the case of the link die.

In your `App.config` file, insert this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Then go to `Project -> Properties` --- right click in your `Project`, then in the `ContextMenu` select `Properties`.

Now go to `Build Events` and add the following code inside the `Post-build event command line` text box (as you can see in the bellow image).

```
; Move all assemblies and related files to lib folder
ROBOCOPY "$(TargetDir) " "$(TargetDir)lib\ " /XF *.exe *.config *.manifest /XD lib logs data /E /IS /MOVE
if %errorlevel% leq 4 exit 0 else exit %errorlevel%
```

[image: Post-build event command line]

**After**

Build your project and say good bye to your OCD!

Comment: Good to know that ! :)

Comment: Note that this breaks debugging on other projects that reference this project for some reason. When executing those other projects, this project is unable to find it's dependent DLLs for some reason.

Comment: Looks like App.config file doesn't work for Net console application or am I missing something?