# Put additional Frameworks like Webkit.Net into a subfolder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webkit, browser, webkit.net

That Webkit.Net project is great and working fine for me.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/

So how could I manage to exclude the dll and other files to separate subfolders? I was thinking about just putting the librarys into subfolder. But somehow I nowhere found a solution that works.

So how can I put the Wekbit.Net into the subfolder **webkit**.

Here some links I already looked through but not found a solution for vb and win forms:

- [How to save DLLs in a different folder when compiling in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110553/how-to-save-dlls-in-a-different-folder-when-compiling-in-visual-studio)
- [C# Putting the required DLLs somewhere other than the root of the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445556/c-sharp-putting-the-required-dlls-somewhere-other-than-the-root-of-the-output)
- [Copy all files and folders using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119271/copy-all-files-and-folders-using-msbuild)
- [NuGet issues with packages.config, project references and the solutionwide packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467094/nuget-issues-with-packages-config-project-references-and-the-solutionwide-packa)
- http://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Add-Libraries.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181484.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Webkit assemblies are neither in the same directory as your application nor in the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you have to tell your program where it can find them.

This answer explains how to resolve assemblies that couldn't been loaded by the [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373295