# C# - Referencing a type in a dynamically generated assembly

Tags: c#, dynamic, assemblies, reference

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible when you are dynamically generating assemblies, to reference a type in a previously dynamically generated assembly.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, @"
namespace Dynamic
{
    public class A
    {
    }
}
");

Assembly assem = results.CompiledAssembly;

CodeDomProvider provider2 = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters2 = new CompilerParameters();

parameters2.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assem.FullName);
parameters2.GenerateInMemory = true;

CompilerResults results2 = provider2.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters2, @"
namespace Dynamic
{
    public class B : A
    {
    }
}
");

if (results2.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    foreach (CompilerError error in results2.Errors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
    }
}
else
{
    Assembly assem2 = results2.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

This code prints the following on the console: `The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I've tried it lots of different ways, but nothing seems to be working.  Am I missing something?  Is this even possible?

EDIT: Fixing the bug in the code provides this error instead:
`Metadata file 'l0livsmn, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be found`

EDIT2:  Bit of a side note, but changing GenerateInMemory to false, and doing `parameters2.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assem.Location);`  will cause it to compile correctly, but I'd greatly prefer to reference the assembly that is directly in memory rather than outputting temporary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that in

```
CompilerResults results2 = provider2.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, @"
namespace Dynamic
{
    public class B : A
    {
    }
}
");
```

You want to pass `parameters2`, not `parameters`.

I found the way to do it, you need NOT to compile the first one in memory, if you don't do that, it will create a dll for this assembly in your temp directory, plus, in your call to

```
ReferencedAssemblies.Add()
```

you dont pass the assembly name, you pass the assembly path, take a look at this code, it should work flawlessly :

```
        CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();            

        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, @"
            namespace Dynamic
            {
                public class A
                {
                }
            }
            ");

        Assembly assem = results.CompiledAssembly;

        CodeDomProvider provider2 = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters parameters2 = new CompilerParameters();

        parameters2.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assem.Location);
        parameters2.GenerateInMemory = true;

        CompilerResults results2 = provider2.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters2, @"
            namespace Dynamic
            {
                public class B : A
                {
                }
            }
            ");

        if (results2.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError error in results2.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Assembly assem2 = results2.CompiledAssembly;
        }
```

Comment: See my second edit.  I think we figured that out at about the same time. I would still like to be able to reference the in-memory assembly, if possible.

Comment: It seems that the source code runs and created the second assembly. But if you try to load the types reside in the second assembly (using assem2.GetTypes() ), you will get a ReflectionTypeLoadException

Comment: in first ompilation the output dll is stored in temp folder. In order to use it you have to save it in your application directory or add a search path as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt9483fk.aspx) says you can:

> **Restrictions on Type References**
>
> Assemblies can reference types defined
>   in another assembly. *A transient
>   dynamic assembly can safely reference
>   types defined in another transient
>   dynamic assembly, a persistable
>   dynamic assembly, or a static
>   assembly.* However, the common
>   language runtime does not allow a
>   persistable dynamic module to
>   reference a type defined in a
>   transient dynamic module. This is
>   because when the persisted dynamic
>   module is loaded after being saved to
>   disk, the runtime cannot resolve the
>   references to types defined in the
>   transient dynamic module.

Comment: Well, I suppose the question now is, "How do I reference the transient dynamic assembly in memory?"

Comment: I wonder: the assembly is created in memory, but is it added to the ApplicationDomain by default?  Or would you load it yourself?  Or call `AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly`?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question.  I tried playing with it a bit, and the dynamically generated assembly definitely seems to be loaded.

Comment: I am having a similar issue!   In my code, I can not get the assem.Location to be defined.   Everything is being loaded and ran in memory.   What do I use for this?   Debugger says it is not being an assigned property.