# Rreference run-time compiled assembly in other run-time compiled assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, codedom, csharpcodeprovider

I'm trying to compile code at runtime that is referenced by an object that is also compiled at run-time in C# .NET 4.6.

I'm using CSharpCodeProvider to generate a CompilerResult in memory. The resulting assembly is referenced in the 2nd code fragment that is compiled. Is it possible to add the AssemblyReference to the CompilerParameters before I compile the 2nd piece (otherwise I'd get a missing assembly compiler error).

Currently I see two options:

1. Create the 1st assembly on disc and use CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add (But I don't like unnecessary disc operations)
2. Do not generate the 1st piece at all but paste the code in the 2nd piece (But I don't like to paste the same code many times)

**So my question: Is there an in-memory way to reference a run-time generated assembly in another run-time generated assembly?**

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830160/c-sharp-referencing-a-type-in-a-dynamically-generated-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSharpCodeProvider` works on a disk anyway - even when you only generate the assembly "in-memory", it compiles the assembly on disk and loads it to memory (it has to, kind of - all it does is call `csc.exe`). The only difference is that the assembly file is a temporary DLL somewhere, rather than a file you specified.

If you want true in-memory compilation of C# code, use the Roslyn compiler.

Comment: Accepted as answer, nice hint with DLL creation on disc, that explains a lot. Also nice hint with the Roslyn compiler.