# Why C# library cannot be found in system32 folder?

Tags: c#, dll, load, file-not-found

Project has a reference to lib. If this lib lays near the executable, all works fine. But I need to put this lib to System32 folder. But in this case project fails, raising filenotfoundexception.

I thought that I can feel myself free to put my libs to system32 folder without any harm for my app.

What's wrong with all this?

Comment: *Why* do you need to put it in the System32 folder? If you need it globally, why not put it in the GAC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve assembly references from another folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260404/resolve-assembly-references-from-another-folder)

Comment: I cannot use my library in the application folder or its subfolder and I thought that simpliest way to use it is to place it to system32 folder.\

Comment: GAC is good option, I think. I will go this way, I think

Comment: Why can't you use the dll in the application folder?

Comment: Application and lib are different projects and must be located in different folders. It is a requirement.

Comment: DLL Hell is something you have to learn to fear.

Answer (score 4):

The .NET runtime doesn't probe for custom DLLs in system32. This article explains how assembly loading and probing works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand how it works now.in my case the only way is GAC

Answer (score 2):

If it's a managed assembly, you need to put it into GAC instead (and that requires strong name).

Comment: Yes, it is really good advice. I already solved my problem with the help of GAC.