# How would I force my executable to load an assembly from a different path?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

I have the following deployment structure:

```
deployment/
    Service1.dll
    Service2.dll
    Service3.dll
    Common.dll
    Host.exe
```

During startup, the 3 service dlls are copied to a temporary location, and I use `Assembly.LoadFrom` to load the them explicitly that way.  My code looks for changes in `deployment` and because these assemblies are loaded in their own AppDomain, I am able to shut them down, copy the new version across, and start them up again.  This works great.

The problem I am having is that all 3 of these services depend on `Common.dll` (the main host executable does *not*).  During startup, this common dll is *also* copied to the temporary location, but the host is resolving the one in `deployment` rather than in my temporary location.

I've tried using `AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath` and pointed it to my temporary location, but it is still resolving to the one in the deployment folder.

Is there some way I can force the CLR to look in my temporary folder *first* before trying to resolve it in the deployment folder (where there are other dependencies, but none that I need to "shadow", as it were).

EDIT: For clarification, if `common.dll` is modified, *all* the services are unloaded first to release the dependency on the common dll before copying and then restarting all 3.

Comment: Could try using the assembly resolve event:
[Resolve Assembly References From Another Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260404/resolve-assembly-references-from-another-folder?rq=1)

Comment: @mungflesh, I was under the impression that event got raised if it couldn't find the assembly...  and in my case, it can - just not the one I want it to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved this using the `AssemblyResolve` event and the current processes directory:

```
                    AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
                    {
                        ApplicationBase = _config.ShadowPath
                    };
                    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(available.Description.ShortName, null, domainSetup);
                    domain.AssemblyResolve += (source, args) =>
                        {
                            int comma = args.Name.IndexOf(',');
                            string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules[0].FileName), args.Name.Substring(0, comma) + ".dll");
                            return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is that common.dll is already loaded by the CLR by the time you make the copy. Are there static members of a type in some other assembly that reference a type in common.dll?

Comment: The Host executable has no dependency on it, and the "shadowing" occurs prior to any loading of the 3 service assemblies in question.  Now, the `Common.dll` *does* depend on assemblies loaded by the Host.exe, but it is not loaded when the host starts (as the host as no dependency on it - doesn't even know it exists).

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your AppDomain have you tried setting the [ApplicationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase.aspx) 
e.g. `appDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase = @"C:\ShadowCopyTest\"`

Comment: Have not tried this yet, but will do.  How will this affect other dependencies in the deployment folder that are not shadowed, or do I have an "all or nothing" approach?

Comment: Everything in the app domain will be affected by the appbase but you can use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event in that scenario.