# Loading dependent .NET assemblies using JNA

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dependencies, jna

I have a .NET (C#) dll which is exporting functions through [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) which is being consumed by a Java application.

This C# dll (let's call it A.dll) has another managed dependency F3BC4DNI.dll.

So, the dependency chain is like: Java class <- JNA <- A.dll <- F3BC4DNI.dll

Don't need to say that all the dlls are included together in the application bin folder.

However, all java binaries run under a process called javaw.exe, then when I try to consume A.dll through JNA, it's looking for F3BC4DNI.dll *inside the javaw.exe path* instead of the same folder as A.dll as can be seen in Process Monitor:

[image: Dependency being searched inside javaw directory]

My guess is that A.dll (.NET) is assuming the **process path** when looking for dependencies.

I've tried a lot of possible solutions like setting PATH environment var, setting JNA library path and also I tried to load the B.dll assembly explicitly inside A.dll using `Assembly.LoadFrom`.

The result is always the same when the Java application is run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:470)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:651)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:395)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
```

When I copy these dlls to the Program Files\Java...bin\ folder, it works, but obviously I don't want to deploy it this way in production.

After all, the only thing I'm assuming is that it's not a problem with Java or JNA side, because it's a .NET related dependency, so I have to somehow tell javaw.exe that .NET dependencies are in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> [...]I have to somehow tell javaw.exe that .NET dependencies are in another folder.
> ```

Just like I suspected, when manually telling to .NET where the dependency is, the problem has been solved, using the answer [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260404/resolve-assembly-references-from-another-folder).

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Object"/> class.
/// </summary>
static A()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bin\\F3BC4DNI.DLL");
        return Assembly.LoadFile(path);
    };
}
```