# How to set Location of dll in builded net app?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

Hello people im asking about setting .Net builded app dll location path

I wanted to make my application files look better and you don't need to see dlls with .exe file

and if you drag dll from folder to folder it will no work.

im using .Net 4.8.

Im adding that im new in C# and if you know answer please solve it with every detail I should know to

prevent many questions from me and Im not perfect at english

Regards Maks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve assembly references from another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260404/resolve-assembly-references-from-another-folder)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but if you have a bunch of dlls you want to reference, I usually create a folder within the project called Libraries and then all my custom dlls (ones I've made, not system ones) I copy to that folder. Then in the solution just go to the references and select add, then navigate to that folder and add them.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your comment too but I mean when you compiled app you have two folders -debug and release and in release I have exe file, pdb, config and dlls and I want to make that there will be special dll folder to make files look better and you can't just move the dlls to this folder because app will not work