# Fail to set probing path in app.config for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a .net7 WPF application with some external assemblies dlls that need to load at runtime and I don't want to place them all in the main exe folder.

I added a configuration file with relative path for the dll location :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="bin\External Dependencies"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and added via nuget the System.Configuration.Configuration package (is this even necessary?)

The config file has the same name as the .exe file and is copied to the output directory, however, running the program I still get exception when trying to run any function that depend on the external dlls  (which goes away if I copy the dlls to the exe folder - but that of course not what I want to do).

Appropriate any help on what I'm missing to make this work.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262129/13448212

Comment: I actually saw this (or something similar) before posting, but I rather not go this path if I don't have to. My case is more simple, where I just have a few dlls that I do want to copy into a sub folder under the main exe folder, and just have the app probe that directory when trying to resolving assemblies.

Comment: You can just add reference and pick a dll in a folder if it's fixed dll. If it's more reference any dll in a given folder dynamically I would consider MEF.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10366