# Error Accessing NuGet from an Inline Task

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, nuget

In Visual Studio 2012 I made an MsBuild inline task that works, until I uncomment a single line of code.  When uncommented it fails with this message:

```
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: The "MyCustomGetPath" task failed unexpectedly.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet, Version=2.7.40906.75, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'NuGet, Version=2.7.40906.75, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018:    at InlineCode.GetNuGetRepositoryPath.Execute()
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: 
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: === Pre-bind state information ===
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: User = Biz\baria2
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: DisplayName = NuGet, Version=2.7.40906.75, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018:  (Fully-specified)
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: Calling assembly : (Unknown).
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: ===
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe.Config
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Using host configuration file: 
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/NuGet.DLL.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/NuGet/NuGet.DLL.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/NuGet.EXE.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/NuGet/NuGet.EXE.
C:\Build\MyScript.targets(49,5): error MSB4018: 
Done Building Project "C:\Build\MyScript.targets" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

The command I am executing is:

```
C:\Build\>msbuild MyScript.targets
```

Here is the inline task:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomGetPath" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <config ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    <repositoryPath ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Reference Include="$(NuGetExePath)" />
    <Using Namespace="NuGet" />
    <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      <![CDATA[
          ISettings settings = null;
          string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(config));
          string fileName = null;
          if (File.Exists(config))
          {
              fileName = Path.GetFileName(config);
          }
          
          //var temp = new NullLogger();
          //MessageLevel msg = MessageLevel.Warning;
          //PhysicalFileSystem physicalFileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(directoryName);

          repositoryPath = directoryName;
          ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Yes, this code is referencing the NuGet.exe (version 2.7 in this case).  There are three commented lines above; uncommenting any one of them will cause the error.  Overall I suspect this is [fusion related](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx).  That reasonably makes sense, but then what are my options to fix this?

### Update

[This post seems to be the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455354/msbuild-inline-task-reference-non-standard-microsoft-assemblies).

Comment: I tried this piece of code in a Console csproj and it loads and compiles fine if I am adding the Nuget reference to Nuget.exe 2.0.0, but it fails to load Nuget.exe 2.7.0 in the compilation itself. So, I suppose Nuget.exe have some problem in loading as assembly or some dependencies are required. Can you give a try on it with Nuget.exe 2.0.0 just for a check whether it works for you?

Comment: During my trial the three commented line, I kept commented itself, because I didn't from where does `PhysicalFileSystem` class falls in and even the `ISettings` as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBuild Inline Task - Reference non-standard Microsoft assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455354/msbuild-inline-task-reference-non-standard-microsoft-assemblies)