# How to check if Obfuscation successful in CSharp project file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, obfuscation, confuserex

Is there code I can include in my CSharp project file to check if ConfuserEx executed properly, and kill the compile process if not?  Maybe use reflection to check if a class name still exists (i.e. has not been obfuscated)?

Update: This is the code in the `.csproj` file that calls the obfuscation routine:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
    <Exec Command="if &quot;$(PlatformName)&quot; == &quot;AnyCPU&quot; (if &quot;$(ConfigurationName)&quot; == &quot;Release&quot; (powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  &quot;$(ProjectDir)confuserEx\confuserps.ps1&quot; &quot;'C:\Program Files\ConfuserEx\Confuser.CLI.exe'&quot; &quot;'$(ProjectDir)confuserEx\confuser.crproj'&quot; &quot;'$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\'&quot; &quot;'$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)'&quot; &quot;'normal'&quot; )&#xD;&#xA;) else (if &quot;$(ConfigurationName)&quot; == &quot;Release&quot; (powershell.exe  -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  &quot;$(ProjectDir)confuserEx\confuserps.ps1&quot; &quot;'C:\Program Files\ConfuserEx\Confuser.CLI.exe'&quot; &quot;'$(ProjectDir)confuserEx\confuser.crproj'&quot; &quot;'$(ProjectDir)obj\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\'&quot; &quot;'$(ProjectDir)obj\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)'&quot; &quot;'normal'&quot; )&#xD;&#xA;)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Running a pre- or post-build task is one way to do it, which one depends on when the obfuscation takes place.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own utility to verify whether obfuscation executes successfully, via libraries such as [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/), or simply use existing tools, such as [Red-Gate Obfuscation Checker](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SA6/Using+the+Obfuscation+Checker).

Comment: Is there a way to script Cecil in the project file to check if a class exists?

Comment: Also, does Red-Gate Obfuscation checker work for other obfuscators besides its own?

Comment: @dashnick To the first question, within your project file, you can [define a build task with inline C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-inline-task) that uses Mono.Cecil and outputs whether obfuscation was detected. Then, within the `AfterCompile` target, you can call the task and then run the Error task if your task said obfuscation was not present.

Comment: Awesome, did not know about inline tasks.  I think that should work! I'll post my solution here if I figure it out.

Comment: Oh, though there may be an issue [if you're using Mono.Cecil, a non-Microsoft assembly, for inline tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455354/msbuild-inline-task-reference-non-standard-microsoft-assemblies). I would still try it and see if it works, but otherwise you might have to just use Base Class Library types.