# Installing .net windows service with lib folder

Tags: c#, windows-services

I would like to create a setup for my windows service.
The dlls of my windows service are placed in /Lib/ folder.

I added an installer class to the service.
And added a custom action on the setup project.

The problem is that when I try to install the service - it fails with the error:
Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in ...

This error happens because the dlls are not in the same directory as the service .exe.
I am using probing in the service config and install util doesn't recognize that probing..

I wanted to find a work around for that problem and tryed in many ways to create
the service using service controller(sc.exe). Trying to run it as a custom action using cmd.exe.
Etc..

This should be a common problem..did anybody find a proper solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, and none of the options suggested in this post or MSDN helped. I figured another solution:

By using Reflector on InstallUtil.exe, I discovered that **InstallUtil is merely a thin wrapper for calling `System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args)`** inside a try/catch block (it also sets the current thread's UI culture and displays the copyright). `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` itself resides in the System.Configuration.Install.dll assembly, accessible to everyone.
Thus, I simply modified the `Program.Main` method of my service to allow installation. See the quick-and-dirty code below:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args != null && args.Any(arg => arg == "/i" || arg == "/u"))
        {
            // Install or Uninstall the service (mimic InstallUtil.exe)
            System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);
        }
        else
        {
            // Run the service
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new MyService() 
            };
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

You can do the same, or create your own version of InstallUtil.

Comment: This is a good solution and worked for me. When the assembly loader executes in the application context, it can find its own assemblies using the probePath, unlike InstallUtil.exe, which doesnt respect the exe.config

Answer (score 0):

You should bind to the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event and do your custom loading in the event handler.

A sample can be found in the first answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net).

Comment: Currently I am just using config binding..
Thats why install util doesn't recognize the dlls..

The service does run when I use Sc.exe..
It just doesn't run using installutil,

Comment: @Lior: I've just undeleted my answer because I think it will work. InstallUtil will have to load your assembly in the CLR, at which time the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event will be raised for all your dependencies. Please give it a try. It makes sense (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

in your config you can add probing path - it's a hint to the runtime where to look for an assembly
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I am using probing. Install util doesn't read the config, I stated this.