# CSE.exe assembly search while compiling

Tags: c#

I am using a batch file with the following commands to successfully compile a C# code on the fly, run the resulting exe and destry the exe.

```
start /wait C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /out:PostillionOutgoing.exe PostillionOutgoing.cs  /reference:AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.dll
call  SetupCI.bat
start /wait PostillionOutgoing.exe
del PostillionOutgoing.exe
```

It works exactly the way I wanted. File `AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.dll` is present in the same folder as the .cs files are.

The assembly `AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.dll` is also needed by a lot of other similar applications. My question is that is there any centralised place where I can keep this DLL so that all the above batch scripts will find it ? By this way I wont have to keep a copy of this DLL in all the separate folders.

I dont want to place the DLL in GAC. I tried in system32 folder also but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /lib command line to specify search folders for references

see msdn docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s5bac5fx.aspx

Comment: I tried the lib option and changed the first line to start /wait C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /lib:C:\Windows\System32\ /out:PostillionOutgoing.exe PostillionOutgoing.cs  /reference:AlexPilotti.FTPS.Client.dll, but still the same error, I have copied that DLL to specified folder though

Comment: I placed in some directory other than System32 and it worked.

Comment: There might be a permission issue using system32 can't say I know my self though.  But I wouldn't want to use that folder anyway, for instance you may want to clear all dlls to ensure they are recreated. Glad to here its working

Comment: One more thing. Is thre any similar thing for runtime also? I mean just for compilation /lib would work. But at run time, I guess it will expect the DLL to be in same folder as the exe. Is there similar thing like /lib for runtime also. So that at runtime, instead of looking for the DLL in the same folder (or GAC) it would look for the DLL in the same folder where the DLL was placed(during compilation) ?

Comment: I actually answered this question originally with that info :)  see this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: I could not find any answer by you (Zonder)

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear in my post I meant I answered this question with the info on adding search paths at runtime.  The post I linked to has code in the first answer, the routine is the same as the second answer just clearer to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720659.aspx), there is no fixed location that the runtime uses when probing for assemblies (i.e. when it looks into directories because it hasn't been able to locate the assembly already).

However, if your assembly is strongly named then you can use a [`<codeBase>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb.aspx) configuration element in your `app.config` to direct the runtime to any path of your choosing.

If your assembly isn't strongly named and you don't want to use `app.config` then unfortunately you are out of options.