# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser put all dependencies in different Folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, chromium, cefsharp

I am using `CefSharp.ChromiumWebBrowser` 49.0.0 in winform Dotnet Framework 4.0

Following files required in executable/Application folder:

```
cef.pak
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
CefSharp.Core.dll
CefSharp.dll
CefSharp.WinForms.dll
cef_100_percent.pak
cef_200_percent.pak
cef_extensions.pak
d3dcompiler_43.dll
d3dcompiler_47.dll
devtools_resources.pak
HAP.dll
icudtl.dat
libcef.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
loc.txt
natives_blob.bin
snapshot_blob.bin
widevinecdmadapter.dll
```

I want to put all these files in separate Folder Not in my application folder.

I have gone through several SO posts like [How to reference C# dll located in different folder to a C# winforms exe in different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510228/how-to-reference-c-sharp-dll-located-in-different-folder-to-a-c-sharp-winforms-e)

But i want all the dependent files of `CefSharp` in different folder or Directory.

How to do that ?

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using? You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element

Comment: i am using Cefsharp version 49.0.0    I have already used private path , its showing   :  Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: You can adapt option 1 from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714 set probing path, set sub process path. Don't set prefer 32bit. The version you are using is too old for me to give you precise instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Copy Local` in References as `False` as : 
[image: References of Project]

use assemblyBinding in App.config as :

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: i have set Copy Local as true, that is why it was showing error.... Setting False resolved the error...