# How to embed a DLL within a C# compiled application

Tags: c#, dll

I made a c# dll.but if the user want to use it in c# winforms he/she must have dll file in the exe folder.
how can i do something with dll project that it automatically add dll to exe file when used in other winforms app?
is it possible?
sorry if my english is not good
tnx

Comment: Set the [copy local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to true

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this DLL? It's possible to load a DLL via Assembly.LoadFrom( )

Comment: Don't think it's possible to do with the DLL, it would require either placing the DLL inside the GAC, or how you build your WinForm.

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways.
here is a full guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx

I love this way to do this in code personally:

[How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the dll in the Global Assembly cache.

Then you can refer to it in the application without needing it to be in the same folder.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are getting at is the programmer wants to use a DLL you have provided, but does not want the DLL to be inside the same folder as the EXE file when compiled.

try this:

[Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Yoy can embed / include DLL files inside the exe file

The key words here is Embedded DLL