# Two different applications using codebase and GAC for loading the same assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, gac

We have 2 different applications (developed with .NET):

1st App: A Winservice.

2nd App: A Desktop App.

The **Desktop App** is loading the assembly from the GAC.
The **Winservice** was in the past doing the same thing, but now we need that the Winservice loads THE SAME ASSEMBLY from another location.

But the GAC is winning and we can´t make this Winservice (using codebase in the app.config) to load the assembly. It always get the GAC´s one.

If we remove the GAC´s one. It works. But we need the other behavior. Desktop from the GAC and Winservice from the defined path in the codebase.

Is this possible without changing the version of the Assembly?

Comment: Where is the assembly relative to the Winservice? Or is it an unknown dynamic value?

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: The location of the assembly is being loaded dynamicly (using CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()). From a location that is not a relative to the Winservice basepath.

Comment: @mclaassen I alredy try currentDomain.AssemblyResolve but the event never gets fired. Maybe because the way we are loading the Assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without some kind of work around that modifies the assembly. In short, the GAC always wins. Period. If an assembly has a strong name the GAC is always checked first. Even if you load it into memory as a byte array and use `Assembly.Load(byte[])`, the strong name will be checked and if it is a GAC'd assembly it gets loaded from the GAC.

A couple possible work arounds:

- Bump the assembly version.
- Resign the assembly with a different strong name key. Build the service referencing this version.