# Windows Service Exception - Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, windows-services, json.net

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` in my Windows Service project.

My `Newtonsoft.Json` version is `6.0.0.0` and I have it referenced in my Project's References.

Installation and compilation go through just fine. But when I start my service from `Services` it throws an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I also searched the web and added the following in my `app.config` file:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
        publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something that might help you here: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Nov/29/Updating-Assembly-Redirects-with-NuGet?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+RickStrahl+%28Rick+Strahl%27s+WebLog%29

Comment: @DavidBrabant I tried it, but didn't help.

Comment: What is your purpose of using Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: @firefalcon I want to convert my array into json and send it through Web Request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to convert array into Json, no need to use outsourced dll's. VS 2010 has `JavaScriptSerializer` to approach this task.

The example is as follows:

`using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = js.Serialize(strYourArrayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is related to startup directory (is 'Newtonsoft.Json' in GAC?).
You can try to work on services to set the directory but I gave up.

Actually I set always copy local for non Microsoft referenced assemblies and I use a source code similar to this
[How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net/23238712#23238712)

Comment: You can put it in Main(). It solves every assembly not found exception.