# Change Assembly Load Path after load

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have a folder "DLLs" where all assemblies are kept related to my project. As per current practice, all the exes (of my project) copy the DLLs from this folder to their "*own*" folder (each exe has its own folder like SupportTools/DbAccess, SupportTools/WebReq ..etc) and when a software is run
it picks the DLLs from its "*own*" folder by default.

I feel this is unnecessary overhead. So I want to eliminate this copy.
I referred yo below link and loaded assemblies from custom path (from DLLs)

[How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net)

But not there is another problem arising.

- Say I have `SomeAssembly.dll`
- I loaded it from DLLs

  `Assembly.LoadFrom(customPath + "SomeAssembly.dll")`
- Now this `SomeAssembly.dll` **depends** on `SomeOther.dll` which is needs at the time of below code

  `assembly.CreateInstance(.."SomeAssembly.dll"..)`
- It fails at this point, as it (might be) searching in current and `SomeOther.dll`isn't present in current application's "*own*" folder

[image]

(Names hidden for obvious reasons)

**How can I make it to look at the custom path at this time ?**

Comment: "I feel this is unnecessary overhead" - why do you think so?

Comment: @Dennis **1.** Coz size of entire application increases due to multiple copies of DLLs   **2.** If in future i add a new DLL which is used by exsiting DLLs, each application would need to add a copy to copy that DLL also to their path

Comment: If you want to reduce application size, just refactor your folder structure: put all executables in the same folder, make sub-folder "DLLs" and add "probing/privatePath" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) into config file for each executable. Otherwise, if those executables must be placed into different folders (for some reasons), copying shared assemblies is a right way to go, and it completely fits .NET deployment ideology via xcopy. Another way is to put them into GAC. Actually, `LoadFrom` could be very error-prone and should be avoided im most scenarios.