# Type mismatch with runtime loaded assembly

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection

I'm writing a plugin architecture for testing purposes (I know there are frameworks to do that), this is how I've done it right now:

I have a common library shared by the main program and the plugins dll, I'll call it `PluginBase` assembly.

That assembly is referenced in a plugin `MyPlugin` which is in the folder `Debug\Plugins`.

It is also referenced in the main program, which is in the folder `Debug`.

The problem is, when I dynamically load the interfaces contained in the `PluginBase`, it gets the interface's `Type` object from the assembly located in `Debug\Plugins`.
But when I try to use the same interface (`IMyPlugin`) in the main program, it loads it from the `PluginBase` assembly located in the `Debug` folder.

And that causes invalid cast exceptions when I try to use the interface in the main Program.

The folder structure:

```
\Debug\MainProgram.exe
\Debug\PluginBase.dll
\Debug\Plugins\MyPlugin.dll
\Debug\Plugins\PluginBase.dll
```

The scenario of the loading is:

- The `ServiceProvider` loads the plugins definition, ans also dynamically loads the interfaces contained in the `PluginBase` assembly (located in `Debug\Plugins`)
- The main program calls the `ServiceProvider` to get a specific interface (but this time loaded from the `Debug` folder)
- The types of the interfaces don't match (even if they are the same)....

I tried to locate the `PluginBase` dll in the `Debug` folder, but then I get compilation issues since the `PluginBase` dll gets copied to the `Debug` folder after the compilation of my plugin project.
Also I don't think this is a clean way to do this.

Is there a way to overcome this problem ? (like perhaps setting a build order in a way?)

Comment: Are you trying to say that there is an `IMyPlugin` in both the PluginBase and MyPlugin projects?

Comment: It's all about the SearchPath, look over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: There should be only 1 `pluginbase.dll` assembly.

Comment: Set the reference for PluginBase in the MyPlugin project to not copy to the output directory.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yep that's what I figured out, but then I have build order problem, should I just exclude the `MyPlugin` project from the solution?

Comment: Also, even if I set not to have a local copy of the dll, when I build the `MyPlugin` project, it still makes a copy of that library....

Comment: I wouldn't place the plugins in a separated path. Else you should add the pluginbase.dll to the GAC (or create a custom resolver)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ok thanks, I'll see what I can do from here :)