# Dynamically load resources from external assembly and find references in same directory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

I'm currently working on a project where I want to automatically build a showcase of all the styles that are defined in the *styling* project of another Visual Studio solution.

To do this, I select the Styling.dll from the at runtime via `OpenFileDialog` from the **other** solutions `bin/Debug` folder, add its resources to my applications resources and then build the views. That works pretty well, but now I've got a problem when selecting an assembly with references to several other assemblies.

This is how I load the assemblies right now:

```
    public void OpenFile()
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "DLL Dateien (*.dll)|*.dll" };
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog.FileName);
            foreach (var dll in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll").Where(dll => dll != openFileDialog.FileName && !dll.ToString().ToLower().Contains("datagrid")))
            {
                this.LoadResources(dll, false);
            }

            this.LoadResources(openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

I put in the `foreach` to first load a Utils.dll that always comes with the Styling.dll, but that obviously doesnt work if there are multiple other assemblies referencing each other.

Then in `LoadResources` :

```
    public void LoadResources(string assemblypath)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblypath);
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");
        if (stream != null)
        {
            var resourceReader = new ResourceReader(stream);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resourceReader)
            {
                // Get all the .baml files from the .dll and create URI for corresponding .xaml files
                if (new FileInfo(resource.Key.ToString()).Extension.Equals(".baml"))
                {
                    var uri = new Uri("/" + assembly.GetName().Name + ";component/" + resource.Key.ToString().Replace(".baml", ".xaml"), UriKind.Relative);

                    // Add ResourceDictionary to Application Resources
                    var rd = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;

                    if (rd != null)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** The exception always throws at the `var rd = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;` point.

Now, how do I get my application to correctly load all the other assemblies in the directory? Right now, I always get an error telling me that the other assemblies could not be found, even though they are in the same directory as the referencing assembly.

After looking for a solution for a while now, I understood that the application automatically tries to find the missing assemblies, but doesn't search in the directory where they actually are.
Since i want to load the assemblies dynamically, I also cant just add additional search paths to my `app.config` beforehand, can I do it at runtime somehow?

I hope you understand my problem, any help is appreciated, thank you!

**Edit:**

I have already read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net), but it didnt help me any further.
When I implement the AssemblyResolve Event, I still get FileNotFound / XamlParse exceptions, even when the file in the `assemblypath` exists.
Also, the handler always tries to find xxx.**resources**.dll files, which on the other hand do not exist in the directory.

Comment: You can use [`AppDomain.ResolveAssembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) to help it find assemblies in other directories.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net) question has an answer with code you can make use of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net)

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that topic, but it didnt help me (or I maybe misunderstood it?)

When the EventHandler reaches the `File.Exists` point, it never finds the file on the specified path, even though it's there.