# NuGet Version mismatch: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, owin

Good morning,

I am trying to develop an application A that will be used by another project B. It builds fine and generates all the DLLs but as soon as project B loads the instance of the main class in project A the following Error occurs..[image: SystemIO]

I have no access to Project B, so I cannot install those dependencies there. The DLLs do definitely exist in the output folder but in different Versions than Project B seems to require.
Project B does not use the DLLs and the NuGets are not installed there, so I don't understand where the required version 2.0.2.0 comes from.

What I did:

- Up/Downgrade to the required version -> different packages fail with the same error
- rename app.config to web.config
- check versions in app.config
- create new project and reinstall everything

So the main question is, where does the required version 2.0.2.0 come from and how to solve the issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with binding redirects in your Project A ? You can also try to resolve the missing dependencies manually as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net).

Comment: @LukasH, what is target framework of your project A and project B. If one is .net core and another is .net framework. It is very possible to cause the problem.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT both target frameworks art .net framework 4.6.2. that shouldn't be causing the problem.

Comment: what I just realized is, that if I replace the version of the dll (4.1.1.0) with the version in the error, I get the same Error but with version 4.1.1.0. I don't understand whats happening here, it is not possible to load two versions of the same assembly at the same time, is it?

Comment: @LukasH, based on my test, I still could not reproduce your problem. Can you provide a reproducible example about your question? For instance, you can provide a small code example about projectA and projectB.