# How to change the path of managed and unmanaged dlls in Visual Studio for C# projects

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to add a managed dll "Emgucv.dll" and unmanaged dll "cvextern.dll"

I have both dlls in the `lib\x64` directory

When I try to add a reference to the managed dll, using Browse, it automatically moves the dll to the root folder of my project. Then it is unable to find the `cvextern.dll` until I also move that to the root of y project and set it to `copy if newer`

However, I would like to keep both dlls in the `lib\x64` directory

Is there a way to add the path to `using Emgu.CV` directive? Or to add a search folder to C# project configuration?

I tried adding to `app.config`

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="lib/x64" />
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But this made no difference

Comment: Is there any updates?Are you using .Net or .Net Framework?

Answer (score 0):

`<probing privatePath="lib/x64" />`  is  for .Net  Framework  and the folder lib must be the sub folder of output folder.  You may need  [Assembly.LoadFrom Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_).

```
  Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("path/managed.dll");
```

Use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke)   to specify the path to load unmanaged dll.

```
 [DllImport("path/x64/Debug/unmanaged.dll")]
```

In addition, check [How to add folder to assembly search path at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net)